# HTML5 to App iOS

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ios, html

Hi I have some question about converting a html5/php page to iOS app with Webmobi or another html5/php to app converter.

If i have a working page that i have made so it will work as a normal webpage, but that i want to run as an app on iOS so it will run on a ipad without internet connection, what do I then need to remember/think of ?

1. Can i just use a normale mySQL database to store data ?
2. is there sone javascript things that i can't use or will the most javascript work when converting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule of thumb: if it works on the mobile browser it will work when wrapped into an app. For the actual wrapping you have several options:

- Create an app with a webview and include the HTML from the device
  locally.
- Use PhoneGap or Titanium as they do this for you and expose a javascript API for you to communicate with the device.

It's important to understand that your app doesn't get 'converted' into native code but that it runs as a website within the app (complete with javascript and css), where the files of the site are stored locally in the application bundle.

You cannot use MySQL as far as I know since that would require an internet connection to a remote MySQL server. You can however use WebSQL or LocalStorage which are both implemented in webkit and accessible through javascript.

When working with dynamic content that need to be loaded from an external server I'd suggest creating an API to interact with that server. You can then retrieve data by using AJAX.

Comment: Okay and thx for the answer, so if I make a php page and use webSQL to save data in, and have a "player add" then the converted "webpage" can still add new players to the webSQL and get data from it ?

Comment: PHP is server side code. Server side code will never run on a phone. It hasn't got a PHP interpreter. WebSQL runs client side and should be accessed via Javascript. If you need to include a database with your app you should include JSON files and read those out with Javascript.

Comment: Please check out this answer for differences between server side and client side: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-difference-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming

Comment: +1 Handy Dandy answer.